# Linq Expression (curry parameter) to be passed to linq to entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

So I was able to complete step one which was just allow someone to use an expression to get to a property that i can compare to a string.

Now I'm trying to take it to the next level where i want people to be able to do the "where" clause and I will subsitute in the value to compare by.    The basic use case is our API's accept a query parameter called `?filterBy:AddressState:VA` .

I'm trying to create something that will be able to generically append clauses to an `IQueryable`.   Basically each API needs to create a dictionary of key/`Expressions` that will do the look up of the property to compare the right side of the `filterBy` e.g. `VA`..  Here is what I have so far but its currently crashing with the error

I'm trying to allow someone to define:

```
public Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<User, string, bool>>> FILTER_BY = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<User, string, bool>>>()  
{
    { "addressstate", (x,inputValue) => x.Address.State == inputValue},   
};
```

Then be able to do in api call:

```
baseQ = baseQ.FilterBy(filterBy, FILTER_BY);
```

But this is where I'm stuck.  I'm trying to figure out how to replace `inputValue` with a string (in this case).

At the end of the day I want to be able to define:

```
(x, inputValue) => x.Address.State == inputValue
```

I want to write something to replace the above  with a new expression to be passed to linq to entities

```
(x) => x.Address.State == "Va"
```

Extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> FilterBy<T, CompareMe>(this IQueryable<T> query, string filterBy, Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<T, CompareMe, bool>>> filterExpressions)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterBy))
        {
            //parse on ':' throw argument if there is not two.
            var split = filterBy.Split(':');
            var key = split[0];
            var right = string.Join("", split.Skip(1));


            var expression  =filterExpressions.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Key == key.ToLower());
             if (expression.Key != null)
            {
                var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), expression.Value.Parameters[0].Name);

                Expression body = new ReplaceVisitor<string>(expression.Value.Parameters[1], right).Visit(expression.Value.Body);
                var lambda =  Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);

                return query.Where(lambda);

            }
       }

    }
```

Here is the ReplaceVisitor:

```
  class ReplaceVisitor <CompareMe> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private CompareMe _value;


     private ParameterExpression _parameter;

     public ReplaceVisitor(ParameterExpression parameter, CompareMe value)
    {
        _parameter = parameter;
        _value = value;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Name == _parameter.Name)
        {
            return Expression.Constant(_value);
        }
        return node;
    }
}
```

I'm using linq to entities, so whatever i put in that where clause needs to be safe to translate to sql.

Error I'm getting:

> ExceptionMessage: "The parameter 'x' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression.",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So eventually I solved it.  I basically needed to use the Visitor to replace the parameter with a constant, and then pass the `original` parameter to the `Expression.Lambda`.

Solution was to change:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), expression.Value.Parameters[0].Name);

Expression body = new ReplaceVisitor<string>(expression.Value.Parameters[1], right).Visit(expression.Value.Body);                   

var lambda =  Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
```

To:

```
Expression body = new ReplaceVisitor<string>(expression.Value.Parameters[1], right).Visit(expression.Value.Body);
 var lambda =  Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, expression.Value.Parameters[0]);
```

Comment: So basically you solved it while I was preparing my answer. Just my replacer is more generic (I'm using it a lot in many expression related postings) +1 though :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple parameter replacer like this

```
static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
{
    return new ParameterReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);
}

class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public ParameterExpression Source;
    public Expression Target;
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return node == Source ? Target : base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

within your method

```
public static IQueryable<T> FilterBy<T, CompareMe>(this IQueryable<T> query, string filterBy, Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<T, CompareMe, bool>>> filterExpressions)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterBy))
    {
        //parse on ':' throw argument if there is not two.
        var split = filterBy.Split(':');
        var key = split[0];
        var value = string.Join("", split.Skip(1));
        var expression = filterExpressions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == key.ToLower()).Value;
        if (expression != null)
        {
            bool stringValue = typeof(CompareMe) != typeof(string);
            var valueExpr = value == null || (!stringValue && value == string.Empty) ?
                Expression.Constant(null, typeof(CompareMe)) :
                Expression.Constant(stringValue ?  value : Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(CompareMe)));
            var body = expression.Body.ReplaceParameter(expression.Parameters[1], valueExpr);
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, expression.Parameters[0]);
            return query.Where(lambda);
        }
    }
    return query;
}
```